# alertDialog won't appear in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, button, dialog, flutter-web

I have a list item when long pressed executes `_selectionAlert` which have two buttons one for delete and one for edit(refer image). Delete works fine but when I press on edit it should execute `_editAlert` which should show another alertDialog but when I click it nothing happens what's the problem here?
This is responsible to show alert dialog in `_selectionAlert`

```
TextButton( // refer code bellow
    child: Text('Edit', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey)),
        onPressed: (){
            _editAlert();
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
        },
)
```

This bellow code runs when item is long pressed:

```
void _selectionAlert(){
      var selItem = AlertDialog(
        title: Text('What you want to do?'),
        content: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            TextButton(       // ignore this it is for deletion this works fine
              child: Text('Delete', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red)),
              onPressed: (){
                _deleteItem();
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
            TextButton( 
              child: Text('Edit', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey)),
              onPressed: (){
                _editAlert();      // this line should call _editAlert
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      );
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context){
          return selItem;
      }
    );
  }
```

Representation of above code:
[image: representation of above code]

```
void _editAlert(){   // edit alertDialog
    var editItem = AlertDialog(
      title: Text('Edit'),
      content: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Edit Item',
            ),
            controller: addeditem,
          ),
          TextButton(
            child: Text('Done'),
            onPressed: (){
              _editItem();
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            }
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context){
        return editItem;
      }
    );
  }
```

PS: edit button is of grey color the button surely is clickable and I am testing on google chrome.
Regards

Comment: I was just wondering I am popping  _selectionAlert when edit is clicked but if it opens and i press done where it will return when popped? I think there must be a different way to call an alertdialog within another alertdialog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add return statement at your _editAlert method

```
_editAlert(){   // edit alertDialog
    var editItem = AlertDialog(
      title: Text('Edit'),
      content: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Edit Item',
            ),
            controller: addeditem,
          ),
          TextButton(
            child: Text('Done'),
            onPressed: (){
              _editItem();
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            }
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
    return showDialog(                //like that
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context){
        return editItem;
      }
    );
  }
```

Also your way is right,you can use poping  for close previous pop up.

Comment: I am having void type so can't return : ( I have tried changing return type to Future<AlertDialog>  didn't work and what I need to do with the return value?

Comment: You can use 'dynamic' return type for your method.Or use Future<T> showDialog<T> but i m not sure about that,you can simply use 'dynamic' . (dynamic  _editAlert(){....})

Comment: Yeah worked!, can I get some resources to read more about it?

Comment: [StatefullBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulBuilder-class.html) **that can help**